# take out the characters in the middle between spaces of a string in r

Tags: r, string, character, space

I have several strings like

"AAA BBB CCC 1X2L BOT BR, DDD EEE FFF 3X4L BOT BR, GGG 5X6L BOT BR"

And I just want to take out the characters before the last last spaces, i.e., I want

"1X2L, 3X4L, 5X6L"

only.

How can I reach this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `sub` after splitting the string on comma (`,`).

```
x <- "AAA BBB CCC 1X2L BOT BR, DDD EEE FFF 3X4L BOT BR, GGG 5X6L BOT BR"
sub('.*?(\\w+)\\s\\w+\\s\\w+$', '\\1', strsplit(x, ',\\s')[[1]])
#[1] "1X2L" "3X4L" "5X6L"
```

`.*?` - matches as few characters as possible until

(`(\\w+)` - is a capture group to capture the word that we want

`\\s` - a whitespace followed by

`\\w+` - a word followed by

`\\s` - another whitespace and a word (`\\w+`) is encountered.)

Comment: Updated the answer with some explanation.

Comment: Thanks! what '\\1' means here?

Comment: It is a backreference to extract what is present in capture group i.e (`(\\w+)`).

Answer (score 1):

Another regex you can use in this case

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "\\d{1}\\w{1}\\d{1}\\w{1}")
#[1] "1X2L" "3X4L" "5X6L"
```

- `\\d{1}`: Matches one digit only
- `\\w{1}`: Matches one letter only